# Qt Creator failed to run on project names containing "update"

Tags: qt, qt-creator

My Qt Creator shows up a very strange behavior: I cannot run projects if there name contains "update".

I have created a completly new Qt widget project "treeviewupdate". When I want to run the app (either in release or in debug), I get this message:

```
Starting D:\build-untitledupdate-Desktop_Qt_5_9_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\untitledupdate.exe...
Failed to start program. Path or permissions wrong?
```

I checked the path settings, permissions, all seams ok. As first I guessed the failure in a too long path name, so I created a second project in the root of my filesystem (D:). But this doesn't help. 
I figured out, that all projects works just fine, if they have a different name.

### Tests

My test names and run reslts are:

- treeviewupdate  [FAIL]
- untitled        [OK  ]
- untitled2       [OK]
- untitledupdate  [FAIL]
- untitledupdat   [OK]
- untitledupdatx  [OK]
- untitledupdatex [FAIL]
- treeviewupdat  [OK]
- treeviewupdatx  [OK]

### Question

Did I something wrong? Can somebody confirm this behavior?

### Notes:

Qt Creator 4.4.1
Based on Qt 5.9.2 (MSVC 2015, 32 bit)
Built on Oct 4 2017 04:12:53
From revision 6afdb8bdf9

All projects are empty "MainWindow"-projects.

Comment: At present `Qt Creator 4.4.1` is the latest edition - I've had issues with their "most recent" release ... have you tried with an older version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by Windows UAC. Windows thinks that you need administrator access when your application name contains words like **Setup** or **Update**. this process is called *[Installer Detection Technology](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709628%28WS.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)* and was introduced alongside UAC with Windows Vista.

You need to set [requestedExecutionLevel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) into your app manifest to avoid this behavior.

Comment: Thats it. I can run my app "test.exe". Simply renaming it to test-update.exe causes windows to ask for administrator access and qt creator does not have these privilege.